# I'm having difficulty adding data my own JSON data to a Firestore Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have begun working with Firebase and I have been stuck trying to figure out how to add my own data. I have been trying to follow the instructions I have found here: [Use A Javascript Class To Upload A Json File To Firebase Firestore](https://www.otcollect.com/collection/firebase/page/k9YdPkWd/use-a-javascript-class-to-upload-a-json-file-to-firebase-firestore)

I am trying to use Visual Studio Code with Node JS. However, I haven't been able to get the code to even run. The most recent error I get is as follows:

```
    Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in C:\Users\****\OneDrive\******\******\App\FirebaseJS\Programs\node_modules\firebase\package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:361:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:697:9)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:565:36)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:634:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\****\OneDrive\Professional\******\App\FirebaseJS\Programs\populateJsonFirestore.js:1:18) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.16.0
PS C:\Users\****\OneDrive\Professional\****\App\FirebaseJS\Programs>
 *  History restored 

PS C:\Users\****\OneDrive\Professional\****\App\FirebaseJS\Programs>
```

What could be the problem at this point. So far the whole process seems quite involved just to add some data. Is there an easier way?